# Pythonで日本語を正規表現によってtxtファイルから助詞等を除きたい

Tags: python

環境 
ubuntu 16.04 lts
python 3.6.0

失礼しました。質問内容に変更が生じたため、こちらのスレッドは解決済みに変更させて頂きます。

申し訳ありません。

さくらのレンタルVPS　512MBプラン

Python初心者です。よろしくお願いします。

ツイートを収集したtxtファイルをMeCabで形態素解析にかけて、頻度順に単語を並べ替えたところ、特殊記号[% & $ #]助詞が大量に含まれていて、うまく処理できていませんでした。

Pythonの正規表現に疎く、どうすれば「て・に・お・は・が・を」等の助詞と特殊記号を処理できるかで悩んでおります。

もし可能であればコードを教えて頂きたいです。

漠然としており申し訳ありません。

以下がテキストファイルの内容になります。

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2d1cd1eee0daf99277a8f4b0a8e21581

どうぞよろしくお願い致します。

求める出力例：
@kanshihoさんの出力例のように名詞だけ綺麗に残して出力したいです。

https://qiita.com/kansiho/items/2b868851b12f0fc0cb24

Comment: MeCabは品詞のタグづけができますから、それで助詞を除外すればいけそうですね。記号も同様に除外したらかなり綺麗になりそうです。

Comment: なるほど。Kenjiさんいつもありがとうございます。品詞のタグ付で調べてみます。

Comment: Pythonのバージョン、使っている辞書、うまく処理できたと期待する出力例があれば他の方もコードで回答できるわうになると思います。

Comment: dokubekoさんありがとうございます。修正させて頂きました。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 失礼しました。質問内容に変更が生じたため、こちらのスレッドは解決済みに変更させて頂きます。お二方申し訳ありません。恐縮ですが、もしよろしければ質問URLを後ほど添付させて頂きますので、回答していただけましたら幸いです。

Comment: 「回答がなされていない質問の、前提が変わってもうこれ以上回答を必要としなくなった場合」にどうするべきなのか、ふと考えてみると方針が定まっていなかったと思うので、メタに投稿してみています。 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2640/754

Comment: Inoueさんありがとうございます。